# Remove mysql 5.6.26-community

Tags: macos, mysql

I installed this version of mysql with the script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MacMiniVault/Mac-Scripts/master/mmvMySQL/mmvmysql.sh), but I don't know how to remove it. It isn't in the applications folder. It's here:

[image]

I wish if someone could tell me how to completely remove it.
Thanks!

Comment: How did you install it? Drag the App or from a .pkg file?

Comment: @IronCraftMan I installed with this command: `bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)` from here [link](http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-yosemite/)

Comment: going to the GitHub link from the article, it appears as if there's not way to uninstall it. I would recommend staying away from the types of software that can't be removed.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Oh, I'm new in OS X and didn't know that.

Comment: also, it appears as if you installed from a .pkg. I can't read whatever language your system is in, but "Instalacions" is fairly close to Installations. Here's an app that will remove the file(s): [UninstallPKG](https://www.corecode.at/uninstallpkg/). If you don't want to pay, this is a link to manually uninstalling it: [article](https://wincent.com/wiki/Uninstalling_packages_(.pkg_files)_on_Mac_OS_X)

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thanks, I installed. But in the list does not appear nothing with that installation. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/beBbzLm.jpg?1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To uninstall all files/packages installed by the shell script simply undo all commands executed in the script logged in with an admin account:

1. Open System Preferences -> MySQL and stop the service if it's running
2. Open the folder /Applications and drag SequelPro - if it was installed - to your trash.
3. Open Terminal and enter `sudo rm -R /usr/local/mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64` to remove the mysql folder
4. Enter `sudo rm /usr/local/mysql` to remove the soft link
5. Enter `cd /Library/LaunchDaemons && ls`
6. Search for the *.mysql.plist (the launch daemon plist of mysql) and remove it with `sudo rm com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`.
7. Remove the my.cnf file with `sudo rm /etc/my.cnf`
8. Remove the mysql socket soft link and the superior folder with `sudo rm -R /var/mysql`
9. Remove all installed mysql package receipts with `sudo pkgutil --forget package-id`.
   Example: `sudo pkgutil --forget com.mysql.launchd` The name of the other two packages are *com.mysql.mysql* and *com.mysql.prefpane*
10. Remove the file MySQL.prefPane in */Library/PreferencePanes/*
11. Finally cd to /usr/local/bin and check the existence as well as the creation/modification date of the file *pidof*. Remove it if both dates match with the installation date of mysql.

---

Addendum

To remove the MySQL installation from System Info -> Software -> Installations (which is a "cosmetic problem" only) remove the MySQL dict entry:

```
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <date>2015-10-13T15:06:35Z</date>
    <key>displayName</key>
    <string>MySQL 5.6.26-community</string>
    <key>displayVersion</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>packageIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.mysql.mysql</string>
        <string>com.mysql.prefpane</string>
        <string>com.mysql.launchd</string>
    </array>
    <key>processName</key>
    <string>installer</string>
</dict>
```

by editing the file InstallHistory.plist in /Library/Receipts/ with `sudo nano /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist` or with TextWrangler.

Comment: For `sudo` to work you need to have administrator rights.

Comment: @klanomath Hi, thanks for answering. I follow all your steps. But it continues appearing in the System Preferences > Software > Installations
I found this file InstallHistory.plist 
`<dict>
  <key>date</key>
  <date>2015-10-12T23:24:29Z</date>
  <key>displayName</key>
  <string>MySQL 5.6.26-community</string>
  <key>displayVersion</key>
  <string></string>
  <key>packageIdentifiers</key>
  <array>
   <string>com.mysql.mysql</string>
   <string>com.mysql.prefpane</string>
   <string>com.mysql.launchd</string>
  </array>
  <key>processName</key>
  <string>installer</string>
 </dict>`

Comment: @klanomath Could it be that in System Preferences > Software > Installations appears that mysql but as a old installation just to keep a history, or it indicates that it remains in the system.

Comment: @klanomath In step 9 I got this output from the terminal `No receipt for 'com.mysql.prefpane' found at '/'.`

Comment: @Joseph That's ok. You already deleted them manually. I modified my answer in step 9 expecting that it also changes the installHistory file but it doesn't. Instead you have to do it manually: see the addendum

Comment: @klanomath It says that its block and I don't have the permision to edit it...

Comment: @Joseph You may do it with `sudo nano /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist` or with [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) using your admin account.

Comment: @klanomath with that I finally could delete mysql! Thanks for answered all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

All the paths to where mysql is installed is in the script.

Under `/usr/local/mysql` the script has installed mysql - so it should just be deleting this mysql folder, that would remove it.